# Repeated roots for polynomial in $\overline{ \mathbb F_{p}}$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let the $ \mathbb F_{p}$ denote the finite field of $\mathbb Z/ p \mathbb Z$ and  $\overline{ \mathbb F_{p}}$ its algebraic closure.

Now let $f(x)=X^p- b \in  \overline{ \mathbb F_{p}}[x]$. I want to $f(x)$ has exactly one root. I know all is derivative are zeroes. How does that prove it has exactly one root?

Comment: All derivatives? 
The first derivative must be constant, no?

Comment: Well, the first derivative is $pX^{p-1}$, which is the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: There is an $\alpha\in \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, such that $f(\alpha)=0$. Show $f(X)=(X-\alpha)^p$.

Answer (score 2):

Working with derivatives is not a good idea here because the characteristic of the fields is positive.

As a hint: Do you know about freshman's dream?

Comment: No, I don't know about it.

Comment: It says that $(x + y)^n = x^n + y^n$. This is not true in general, but if everything takes place in a field of characteristic $p > 0$ and $n$ is a power of $p$, then it is true. Can you now prove that freshman's dream is true in this case? Can you use it to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I can show that.Then I can prove $X^p-b=(X-a)^p$ where $a$ is  one solution of the equation $X^p-b$.