# If $f$ has no repeated roots then $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are coprime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

When our lecturer defined a seperable polynomial, he said:

> A non-constant irreducible polynomial $f\in F[x]$ is called *seperable* if the two equivalent conditions hold:
>
> 1. $f$ has no repeated roots in $\overline{F}$.
> 2. $\gcd(f, f')=1$.

I'm not convinced that these two are always equivalent.

I know that "not 1" implies "not 2", therefore 2 implies 1 ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33910/when-polynomials-fx-and-fx-are-relatively-prime-fx-has-no-repeated-roots)).
However, when I try proving the second direction, this happens:

$f$ is irreducible, hence either $\gcd(f, f')=1$ or $f|f'$. Assume [by contrary] that the second holds. Since $\deg f> \deg f'$, it implies that $f'=0$.
Now, if $char F=0$, we can conclude that $f$ is constant and that finishes (as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312936/if-px-in-fx-is-irreducible-and-f-has-characteristic-zero-then-px-ha)).
But what about the finite characteristic case?
 **Is it possible that $f'=0$, yet $f$ has no repeated roots in $\overline{F}$?**

[I've tried $x^p-b$ as an example but [it fails](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126841/repeated-roots-for-polynomial-in-overline-mathbb-f-p?rq=1).]

Answer (score 1):

In characteristic $p$, if $f'$ is the zero polynomial, then $f(x)=g(x^p)$ for some polynomial $g$, so $f(x)=(g(x))^p$, so repeated roots.

Comment: Oh, your'e right. Frobenius endomorphism to the rescue again. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, that works only if $a^p=a$ for all $a\in F$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. So, it works over the field of $p$ elements, but over extensions of that field your $x^p-b$ should be a counterexample.